# Connecting to Sage 300 .net libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, sage-300

I am trying to connect to Sage 300 tables with the native connection through the Sage 300 .Net Library. I recorded a macro and converted it to C#. I have this code in a class. Maybe I am not declaring the function well. Now I want to write a method in my controller to the test the connection. I am just confused on how to continue at this point

```
  public CallResult<String> PostJournal()
    {

        //calling start of sage session
        Session session;
        int a = -1;
        //database link for sage
        DBLink mDBLinkCmpRW;
        ViewFields viewDetails;
        CallResult<String> result = new CallResult<String>();

        try
        {            
            session = new Session();

            //Initialisation of Sage to get the version
            session.Init("", "XY", "XY1000", GetSageVersion());

            //accessing of database with sage credentials
            session.Open("ADMIN", "ADMIN", GHOO, DateTime.UtcNow, 0);
            //start of code for inserting 

            try
            {

                mDBLinkCmpRW = session.OpenDBLink(DBLinkType.System, DBLinkFlags.ReadWrite);
                a = 2;

                // tables to be posted to are found below
                View GLBATCH1batch = mDBLinkCmpRW.OpenView("GL0008");
                var GLBATCH1batchFields = GLBATCH1batch.Fields;
                View GLBATCH1header = mDBLinkCmpRW.OpenView("GL0006");

                var GLBATCH1headerFields = GLBATCH1header.Fields;
                View GLBATCH1detail1 = mDBLinkCmpRW.OpenView("GL0010");
                var GLBATCH1detail1Fields = GLBATCH1detail1.Fields;
                View GLBATCH1detail2 = mDBLinkCmpRW.OpenView("GL0402");

                GLBATCH1batch.Compose(new View[] { GLBATCH1batch });
                GLBATCH1header.Compose(new View[] { GLBATCH1batch, GLBATCH1detail1 });
                GLBATCH1detail1.Compose(new View[] { GLBATCH1detail2 });
                GLBATCH1detail2.Compose(new View[] { GLBATCH1detail1 });

                var GLBATCH1detail2Fields = GLBATCH1detail2.Fields;
                View GLPOST2 = mDBLinkCmpRW.OpenView("GL0030");
                var GLPOST2Fields = GLPOST2.Fields;

                GLBATCH1batch.Browse("(BATCHSTAT = \"1\" OR BATCHSTAT = \"6\" OR BATCHSTAT = \"9\")", true);
                GLBATCH1batch.RecordCreate(ViewRecordCreate.Insert);

                GLBATCH1batch.Read(true);
                GLBATCH1batchFields.FieldByName("PROCESSCMD").SetValue("1", true);
                ////  Lock Batch Switch
                GLBATCH1batch.Process();
                GLBATCH1headerFields.FieldByName("BTCHENTRY").SetValue("", false);
                ////  Entry Number
                GLBATCH1header.Browse("", true);
                //"";
                //1;
                GLBATCH1header.Fetch(true);
                GLBATCH1headerFields.FieldByName("BTCHENTRY").SetValue("00000", true);
                GLBATCH1header.RecordCreate(ViewRecordCreate.DelayKey);
                //2;
                var temp = GLBATCH1header.Exists;
                GLBATCH1batchFields.FieldByName("BTCHDESC").SetValue("Testing Journal", true);
                ////  Description
                GLBATCH1batch.Update();
                var temp1 = GLBATCH1detail1.Exists;
                GLBATCH1detail1.RecordClear();
                var temp2 = GLBATCH1detail1.Exists;
                GLBATCH1detail1.RecordCreate(ViewRecordCreate.NoInsert);
                //0;
                GLBATCH1detail1Fields.FieldByName("ACCTID").SetValue("230000", true);
                GLBATCH1detail1Fields.FieldByName("TRANSDESC").SetValue("testing journal", true);
                ////  Description
                GLBATCH1detail1.Process();
                GLBATCH1detail1Fields.FieldByName("SCURNAMT").SetValue("2000.000", true);
                GLBATCH1detail1.Insert();
                GLBATCH1detail1Fields.FieldByName("TRANSNBR").SetValue("-000000001", true);
                ////  Transaction Number
                GLBATCH1detail1.Read(true);
                var temp3 = GLBATCH1detail1.Exists;
                GLBATCH1detail1.RecordCreate(ViewRecordCreate.NoInsert);
                //0;
                GLBATCH1detail1Fields.FieldByName("ACCTID").SetValue("260035", true);
                GLBATCH1detail1Fields.FieldByName("TRANSDESC").SetValue("testing journal", true);
                ////  Description
                GLBATCH1detail1.Process();
                GLBATCH1detail1Fields.FieldByName("SCURNAMT").SetValue("-2000.000", true);
                GLBATCH1detail1.Insert();
                GLBATCH1detail1Fields.FieldByName("TRANSNBR").SetValue("-000000002", true);
                ////  Transaction Number
                GLBATCH1detail1.Read(true);
                GLBATCH1batch.Read(true);
                var temp4 = GLBATCH1header.Exists;
                GLBATCH1headerFields.FieldByName("JRNLDESC").SetValue("testing journal", true);
                ////  Description
                GLBATCH1header.Insert();
                GLBATCH1header.Read(true);
                var temp5 = GLBATCH1header.Exists;
                GLBATCH1batch.Read(true);
                GLBATCH1headerFields.FieldByName("BTCHENTRY").SetValue("00000", true);
                GLBATCH1header.RecordCreate(ViewRecordCreate.DelayKey);
                //2;
                var temp6 = GLBATCH1header.Exists;
                GLBATCH1headerFields.FieldByName("BTCHENTRY").SetValue("00001", true);
                GLBATCH1header.Read(true);
                GLBATCH1batch.Read(true);
                GLBATCH1batch.Read(true);
                GLBATCH1batch.Process();
                var temp7 = GLBATCH1header.Exists;
                GLBATCH1detail1Fields.FieldByName("TRANSNBR").SetValue("0000000020", true);
                ////  Transaction Number
                GLBATCH1detail1.Read(true);
                GLBATCH1batch.Read(true);
                var temp8 = GLBATCH1header.Exists;
                GLBATCH1batchFields.FieldByName("PROCESSCMD").SetValue("2", true);
                ////  Lock Batch Switch
                GLBATCH1batch.Process();
                GLBATCH1batchFields.FieldByName("RDYTOPOST").SetValue("1", true);
                ////  Ready to Post
                GLBATCH1batch.Update();
                GLBATCH1batch.Update();
                GLBATCH1batchFields.FieldByName("PROCESSCMD").SetValue("0", true);
                ////  Lock Batch Switch
                GLBATCH1batch.Update();
                GLBATCH1batch.Process();
                GLPOST2Fields.FieldByName("BATCHIDFR").SetValue("000030", true);
                ////  From Batch Number
                GLPOST2Fields.FieldByName("BATCHIDTO").SetValue("000030", true);
                ////  To Batch Number
                GLPOST2.Process();
                GLBATCH1batch.Read(true);
                GLBATCH1batch.Read(true);
                GLBATCH1detail1Fields.FieldByName("TRANSNBR").SetValue("0000000020", true);
                ////  Transaction Number
                GLBATCH1detail1.Read(true);
                //return;

                result.Success = 1;

                result.Model = "OK";
                //end of code to insert

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result.Success = 0;
                var errors = session.Errors;
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
                a = 16;


            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.Success = 0;

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

            result.Errors = ex.Message + " " + a.ToString();



        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Where did you write this method? If not already, you can write method in a class and use an object of that class in MVC controller to call this method.

Comment: This is the only method to connect to Sage 300 endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised the version I had were different so I had to change it and i got connected to make it work.Also I had to specify the database I would use correctly.

```
public CallResult<String> PostJournal()
{

    //calling start of sage session
    Session session;
    int a = -1;
    //database link for sage
    DBLink mDBLinkCmpRW;
    ViewFields viewDetails;
    CallResult<String> result = new CallResult<String>();

    try
    {            
        session = new Session();

        //Initialisation of Sage to get the version
        session.Init("", "XY", "XY1000", GetSageVersion());

        //accessing of database with sage credentials
        session.Open("ADMIN", "ADMIN", GHOH, DateTime.UtcNow, 0);
        //start of code for inserting 

        try
        {

            mDBLinkCmpRW = session.OpenDBLink(DBLinkType.System, DBLinkFlags.ReadWrite);
            a = 2;

            // tables to be posted to are found below
            View GLBATCH1batch = mDBLinkCmpRW.OpenView("GL0008");
            var GLBATCH1batchFields = GLBATCH1batch.Fields;
            View GLBATCH1header = mDBLinkCmpRW.OpenView("GL0006");

            var GLBATCH1headerFields = GLBATCH1header.Fields;
            View GLBATCH1detail1 = mDBLinkCmpRW.OpenView("GL0010");
            var GLBATCH1detail1Fields = GLBATCH1detail1.Fields;
            View GLBATCH1detail2 = mDBLinkCmpRW.OpenView("GL0402");

            GLBATCH1batch.Compose(new View[] { GLBATCH1batch });
            GLBATCH1header.Compose(new View[] { GLBATCH1batch, GLBATCH1detail1 });
            GLBATCH1detail1.Compose(new View[] { GLBATCH1detail2 });
            GLBATCH1detail2.Compose(new View[] { GLBATCH1detail1 });

            var GLBATCH1detail2Fields = GLBATCH1detail2.Fields;
            View GLPOST2 = mDBLinkCmpRW.OpenView("GL0030");
            var GLPOST2Fields = GLPOST2.Fields;

            GLBATCH1batch.Browse("(BATCHSTAT = \"1\" OR BATCHSTAT = \"6\" OR BATCHSTAT = \"9\")", true);
            GLBATCH1batch.RecordCreate(ViewRecordCreate.Insert);

            GLBATCH1batch.Read(true);
            GLBATCH1batchFields.FieldByName("PROCESSCMD").SetValue("1", true);
            ////  Lock Batch Switch
            GLBATCH1batch.Process();
            GLBATCH1headerFields.FieldByName("BTCHENTRY").SetValue("", false);
            ////  Entry Number
            GLBATCH1header.Browse("", true);
            //"";
            //1;
            GLBATCH1header.Fetch(true);
            GLBATCH1headerFields.FieldByName("BTCHENTRY").SetValue("00000", true);
            GLBATCH1header.RecordCreate(ViewRecordCreate.DelayKey);
            //2;
            var temp = GLBATCH1header.Exists;
            GLBATCH1batchFields.FieldByName("BTCHDESC").SetValue("Testing Journal", true);
            ////  Description
            GLBATCH1batch.Update();
            var temp1 = GLBATCH1detail1.Exists;
            GLBATCH1detail1.RecordClear();
            var temp2 = GLBATCH1detail1.Exists;
            GLBATCH1detail1.RecordCreate(ViewRecordCreate.NoInsert);
            //0;
            GLBATCH1detail1Fields.FieldByName("ACCTID").SetValue("230000", true);
            GLBATCH1detail1Fields.FieldByName("TRANSDESC").SetValue("testing journal", true);
            ////  Description
            GLBATCH1detail1.Process();
            GLBATCH1detail1Fields.FieldByName("SCURNAMT").SetValue("2000.000", true);
            GLBATCH1detail1.Insert();
            GLBATCH1detail1Fields.FieldByName("TRANSNBR").SetValue("-000000001", true);
            ////  Transaction Number
            GLBATCH1detail1.Read(true);
            var temp3 = GLBATCH1detail1.Exists;
            GLBATCH1detail1.RecordCreate(ViewRecordCreate.NoInsert);
            //0;
            GLBATCH1detail1Fields.FieldByName("ACCTID").SetValue("260035", true);
            GLBATCH1detail1Fields.FieldByName("TRANSDESC").SetValue("testing journal", true);
            ////  Description
            GLBATCH1detail1.Process();
            GLBATCH1detail1Fields.FieldByName("SCURNAMT").SetValue("-2000.000", true);
            GLBATCH1detail1.Insert();
            GLBATCH1detail1Fields.FieldByName("TRANSNBR").SetValue("-000000002", true);
            ////  Transaction Number
            GLBATCH1detail1.Read(true);
            GLBATCH1batch.Read(true);
            var temp4 = GLBATCH1header.Exists;
            GLBATCH1headerFields.FieldByName("JRNLDESC").SetValue("testing journal", true);
            ////  Description
            GLBATCH1header.Insert();
            GLBATCH1header.Read(true);
            var temp5 = GLBATCH1header.Exists;
            GLBATCH1batch.Read(true);
            GLBATCH1headerFields.FieldByName("BTCHENTRY").SetValue("00000", true);
            GLBATCH1header.RecordCreate(ViewRecordCreate.DelayKey);
            //2;
            var temp6 = GLBATCH1header.Exists;
            GLBATCH1headerFields.FieldByName("BTCHENTRY").SetValue("00001", true);
            GLBATCH1header.Read(true);
            GLBATCH1batch.Read(true);
            GLBATCH1batch.Read(true);
            GLBATCH1batch.Process();
            var temp7 = GLBATCH1header.Exists;
            GLBATCH1detail1Fields.FieldByName("TRANSNBR").SetValue("0000000020", true);
            ////  Transaction Number
            GLBATCH1detail1.Read(true);
            GLBATCH1batch.Read(true);
            var temp8 = GLBATCH1header.Exists;
            GLBATCH1batchFields.FieldByName("PROCESSCMD").SetValue("2", true);
            ////  Lock Batch Switch
            GLBATCH1batch.Process();
            GLBATCH1batchFields.FieldByName("RDYTOPOST").SetValue("1", true);
            ////  Ready to Post
            GLBATCH1batch.Update();
            GLBATCH1batch.Update();
            GLBATCH1batchFields.FieldByName("PROCESSCMD").SetValue("0", true);
            ////  Lock Batch Switch
            GLBATCH1batch.Update();
            GLBATCH1batch.Process();
            GLPOST2Fields.FieldByName("BATCHIDFR").SetValue("000030", true);
            ////  From Batch Number
            GLPOST2Fields.FieldByName("BATCHIDTO").SetValue("000030", true);
            ////  To Batch Number
            GLPOST2.Process();
            GLBATCH1batch.Read(true);
            GLBATCH1batch.Read(true);
            GLBATCH1detail1Fields.FieldByName("TRANSNBR").SetValue("0000000020", true);
            ////  Transaction Number
            GLBATCH1detail1.Read(true);
            //return;

            result.Success = 1;

            result.Model = "OK";
            //end of code to insert

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.Success = 0;
            var errors = session.Errors;
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
            a = 16;


        }


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.Success = 0;

        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        result.Errors = ex.Message + " " + a.ToString();



    }

    return result;
}
```